# How do I remove the calendar dashicon from posts in Wordpress Sparkling theme?

Tags: css, wordpress, icons

The site in question:

`www.suzannelagrande.com`

I was able to remove the date/time but the dashicon remains. I found the CSS for it:

`content: "\f508";`

It's identical to the calendar dashicon here:
http://melchoyce.github.io/dashicons/

And yet that code is not in the CSS...?

Comment: where is the dash icon showing?

Comment: You could add in your css file: .fa-calendar { display: none; } or delete from your html file <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>.